# Wifi to pass through aluminium

Tags: wifi

I am about to make an rc car which uses a wifi connection. The body for the car would be made from aluminium and the wifi receiver will be placed inside this aluminium casing.

How do I make sure that this will work?

Would I be forced to change my material or can I just make an extension for the receiver and make sure it is out of the casing?

If so , would that really help me?

Comment: As long as the antenna is outside the casing, radio communications such as wifi should work fine.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an external onmidirectional wifi antenna, like [these on ebay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=omni%20wifi%20antenna&_fscr=1).

If your wifi chip does not have a U-FL connector, you can use a SMA to U-FL adapter or directly a SMA Antenna.

Answer (score 0):

Your Wifi signals should be able to penetrate aluminum. Wifi uses radio waves which can go through some thick material. I know that Wifi signals pass through steel. The best way for you to know is to try. If it does not work, drill a hole in your casing and use an antennae.